# Haskell: “where” clause with multiple top-level bindings?

Tags: haskell

This has got to be a FAQ, but I can’t find it among a blizzard of questions about `let` vs `where`, so… I would like to factor an expression out of multiple top-level bindings, while scoping it only to those bindings. I can do this if I have a single binding, with a “where” clause:

```
foo = ... bar ... bar ...
    where bar = ...
```

and also if I have multiple guarded equations for the same top-level binding:

```
foo = x | ... bar ...
        | ... bar ...
    where bar = ...
```

but there seems to be no way to have multiple top-level bindings in scope of the “where,” that is something like this:

```
foo = ... bar ...
baz = ... bar ...
    where bar = ...
```

I have to define `bar` at the top level too. It’s not a big deal, but it would be nice to scope it more closely. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're not missing something, it's just that a `where` applies only to a single expression.  So with your first example, you have only one expression, in your second example the single expression is your guard, and in the third case you have two difference expressions.  For reference, you can see the technical description of Haskell 98 syntax [here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html), but the relevant part is

```
rhs    ->  = exp [where decls]
       |   gdrhs [where decls]
```

Which states that a right-hand side of a definition can consist of an expression with an optional `where` with declarations, or a guard right-hand side with an optional `where` with declarations.

If you need a binding with two functions you're going to have to define it in the same scope, that's just how it works.

---

There is a workaround, though.  You can do something like

```
foo :: Int
bar :: String
(foo, bar) = (2 * baz, show baz)
    where baz = 1
```

But I personally would prefer to see `baz` at the top level rather than `(foo, bar)` defined at the top level.